# Order relations and counting the number of cases (Fubini numbers)

Tags: combinatorics, relations, order-theory

I have $n=2$ numbers $a$ and $b$, $a\in\Bbb{N}$ and $b\in\Bbb{N}$.

Then I have the function $f$ defined as:

$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
-1,  & \text{if $x<y$} \\
0, & \text{if $x=y$} \\
+1, & \text{if $x>y$}
\end{cases}
$

Now with $f$ and the $n=2$ numbers $a$ and $b$ I have $m=3$ cases which are:

1. $a<b$
2. $a=b$
3. $a>b$

How much will be $m$ when I increase $n$?

Let's say $n=3$ and so I have $a$, $b$ and $c$, my $m$ cases are

1. $a=b$ and $b=c$
2. $a=b$ and $b<c$
3. $\ldots$

How can I count all of them?

**Update:**

The answer is [Fubini numbers](https://oeis.org/A000670).

Comment: So you're asking how many ways to order $n$ objects, but you're allowed "orderings" where objects are considered equal?

Comment: @Arthur It seems to me that what you wrote in your comment is equivalent to my question but I am not 100% sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak A$ be the set of all partitions of $X = \{ 1, \dots, n\}$. Then I believe the number you're looking for is
$$
\sum_{A \in \mathfrak A} \lvert A \rvert !
$$
for which I doubt there is a simple expression.

For instance when $n = 2$
$$
{\mathfrak A} = \{ \{ \{ 1, 2\} \}, \{ \{1\}, \{2 \}\} \}.
$$
The partition $\{ \{ 1, 2\} \}$ corresponds to $a_{1} = a_{2}$, and the partition $\{ \{1\}, \{2 \}\}$ corresponds to the two cases $a_{1} > a_{2}$ and $a_{2} > a_{1}$.
And your number is indeed
$$
1! + 2! = 3.
$$

For $n = 3$ one should have
$$
{\mathfrak A} = \{ \{ \{ 1, 2, 3\} \}, \{ \{1, 2\}, \{3 \} \},
\{ \{1, 3\}, \{2 \} \}, \{ \{2, 3\}, \{1 \} \}, \{ \{1\} , \{2\}, \{3 \}\}\}.
$$
Here the first partition corresponds to $a_{1} = a_{2} = a_{3}$, the second to the two cases $a_{1} = a_{2} > a_{3}$ and $a_{3} > a_{1} = a_{2}$, etc., and the last one to the six cases when $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}$ are distinct.
And your number should be
$$
1! + 3 \cdot 2! + 3! = 13.
$$

Comment: Do you mean "Fubini numbers"? See https://oeis.org/A000670

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson, definitely, except that I wasn't aware of the name. Thanks. Should have looked up OEIS!